Problem running app because cant import LinearGradient from kivy.graphics
I cant run the app i was working after using kivy graphics
i try unistall and install kivy, upgrade kivy, install LinearGradient, import LinearGradient alone
enter image description here
Some way to resolve this problem, before I use graphics the app was running ok, but when I finish with the logic of buttons, database etc I try use themes for GUI but now Cant running the app with this problem of LinearGradinet

Please do not post images of code/errors/data. Instead post the code/errors/data as text in a code block.

Did you install LinearGradient from kivy.garden? If so, try importing it from kivy.garden: from kivy.garden.lineargradient import LinearGradient

thanks, this was my first post, didnt know about that about images
